# Rigify generate error

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigify

Hi im having a mayor problem in rigify 
When I generate a rig with rigify from "Human (Meta-Rig)" I get the message

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "...\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\rigify\ui.py" , line 286, in execute generate.generate_rig(context, context.object)

File "...\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\rigify\generate.py", line 141, in generate_rig bone_gen = obj.data.bones[bone.name]

KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "hips" not found'

location: :-1

What shall i do ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your meta rig does not have a bone named *hips*, which the script expects.

check that you haven't renamed any bones in your metarig. If you do, you will have to revert the corresponding bones back to their original names. You may want to create a new metarig to compare to in order to do this.

Comment: the problem is that the rig actually has a bone named Hip, i dont understand why i doesnt  not work---- heres the link to the file in case theres a chance of fix it u.u    https://www.mediafire.com/?kaqpqd3555g37kw